# Match function is giving wrong results

Tags: javascript, regex, angular, typescript, match

I'm trying to do match a phone number with a regular expression:

```js
this.Formareamedia.get('ladacontacto').valueChanges.subscribe((lada) => {
  let p;
  if (lada.length == 5) {
    p = '\\d{3}.\\d{4}';
  } else {
    p = '\\d{4}.\\d{4}';
  }
  this.Formareamedia.get("telefonocontacto").setValidators(Validators.pattern(new RegExp(p)));
  this.Formareamedia.get("telefonocontacto").updateValueAndValidity();
  this.ladacontacto = lada;
  let telefono = this.Formareamedia.get('telefonocontacto').value;
  console.log(new RegExp(p).lastIndex);
  if (telefono && telefono.match(new RegExp(p))) {
    return null;
  } else {
    return {
      telefono: false
    }
  }
});
```

If I put in the lada input `(XX)` and in the telefono input `XXXX-XXXX` the function is returning `true` (a correct result), but if I put in the lada input `(XXX)` and in the telefono input `XXXX-XXXX` is returning `true` a wrong result it is supposed to return `false`. What's wrong with my function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to `anchor` your regex to the `end of the string`, like this:

```
 if (lada.length == 5) {
    p = '^\\d{3}.\\d{4}$';
  } else {
    p = '^\\d{4}.\\d{4}$';
  }
```

Otherwise it will match at least the number you specify (ignoring extra digits).

The same applies to the beginning of string: Specify '`^`'.

With '`$`' at the end it will ensure that the string ends with your digits.

Comment: It's correct thank you!!